# Mef does not detect open generic type in MsTest project but does in console app

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, mef, mstest

I am experiencing some strange behavior when using MEF with an open generic Export in a unit test project.

Type definition:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<out TDataSource, TE>
{

}

[Export(typeof(ISomeInterface<,>))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SomeClass<TDataSource, TE> : ISomeInterface<TDataSource, TE>
{

}
```

In a console app this resolves fine

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new CompositionContainer(
        new AggregateCatalog(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ISomeInterface<,>).Assembly)));

    var something = container.GetExportedValue<ISomeInterface<string, int>>();

}
```

In a unit test project however mef will not add the type SomeClass to its catalog

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var container = new CompositionContainer(
        new AggregateCatalog(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IInterface<>).Assembly)));

    var exportedValue2 = container.GetExportedValue<ISomeInterface<string, int>>();
}
```

I use VS2013 and .Net 4.5.1

Is this a bug or do I have an error somewhere?